# How to link User Data in aspnet_Users and Users tables in DotNetNuke

Tags: sql, sql-server, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I'm creating a module for DNN 7.3.4. Another bought module creates new users. I need to display a list of those users in my module using an SQL statement. However the other module creates them in the table aspnet_Users and also adds their details into the Users table.

I cant see how I can link the records in both tables as the userid in the aspnet_Users table takes the form of "6c9c37b9-0a9a-4394-aad5-715e63681024" whereas the Users table UserID field contains "1".

Answer (score 1):

The link there is the "username" field in both tables.

If you are trying to display users from your own module, you should only look at the DNN Users table, and UserPortals, I would ignore everything in the ASPNET_ tables, just let DNN maintain that link.